# Error GPRC con Geocoder en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas, alguien sabe porque de un mes para aca al utilizar getFromLocation con Geocoder, da un error IOException: GRPC failed.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public String getCountryCode(Context context) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        //Address adr=(Address)geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        //return adr.getCountryCode();
        if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
            return addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
        }
        //Address result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //do something
        e.printStackTrace();
        //return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estas usando Genymotion?

Comment: Geocoder no funciona en Android emulator, necesitas utilizar un dispositivo físico.

Answer (score 0):

Comentas que hace tiempo funcionaba sin problema y ahora obtienes el error:

> error IOException: GRPC failed.

primeramente revisa que tu API esta habilitada en:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

---

Revisa la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), que indica usar el método [isPresent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#isPresent()) para determinar si la implementación Geocoder existe, puede ser que el dispositivo o emulador usado no lo soporte, ejemplo:

```
public String getCountryCode(Context context) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());

     if(geocoder.isPresent()){
        Log.i("GEOCODER", "Geocoder presente!");
     }else
       Log.e("GEOCODER", "Geocoder no soportado"); 
       return null;
     }

    List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        //Address adr=(Address)geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        //return adr.getCountryCode();
        if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
            return addresses.get(0).getCountryCode();
        }
        //Address result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //do something
        e.printStackTrace();
        //return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Si existe, asegura que los valores de latitud (latitude) y longitud son validos (longitude).

Comment: Geocoder funciona correctamente, y antes funcionaba en el emulador, pero algo ha debido de cambiar no sé si en código, api o no sé...